# Angular 6 impossible to import css in styles section of angular.json

Tags: css, angular

I'm migrating a project to Angular 6 and I'm trying to import my css file in styles section on angular.json:

```
"styles": [
      "./src/styles.css",
      "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
      "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

but it doesn't work. Css are correctly imported but class are not applied, except for class in style.css.
Instead, it correctly work for js imported in scripts section.
Any ideas? Thanks

The folder structure is:

```
app --
     |-- node_modules
     |-- src
       |.. styles.css
     |-- angular.json
```

Comment: can you post the hierarchy of your folder structure?

Comment: Thanks Ritesh, I edited the post.

Comment: Can you please try removing ./?

Comment: add like this ../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css

Comment: You need to load styles.css at the last. In your case after bootstrap css

Comment: I tried to remove ./ but it doesn't work. I also tried with ../ but nothing changes...

Answer (score 1):

In my angular 6 app this is how I import css files:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
          "node_modules/pure-css-loader/dist/css-loader.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ]
```